# Meaning of fiddler's icon of green arrow pointing to the right?

Tags: fiddler

I'm using fiddler and for a web service call I get this [image: green arrow] listed in the Web Sessions.

I don't see the meaning of this listed in the help (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/ui.asp) and I searched the Discussion Group.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates that the request was a HTTP POST request. (Docs updated, thanks)